# How to replace odoo address with domainname

Tags: nginx, dns, odoo, domain-name

Hello I made an odoo website, added the addres to my DNS, so whenever someone browses to www.mycompany.com they're redirected to the odoo server, but the address with port 8069 is still displayed.

Any ideas how I can hide this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use a reverse Proxy like Nginx : http://www.schenkels.nl/2014/12/reverse-proxy-with-odoo-8-nginx-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: I tried this, but without any result, I still get the address:port when I browse to my domain...